# Quickest way to get bytes from type long

Tags: java, arrays, get, byte, long-integer

this is

```
Long number = 0x001122334455667788L;
```

i need create `byte[]` of last 6 bytes of Long.

So its will be look like

```
byte[] bytes = {0x22,0x33,0x44,0x55,0x66,0x77,0x88};
```

What is the right way to make something like this?

Thanks for any responnse

Comment: Your `number` is more than 64 bits and your `bytes` is **7** bytes long, not 6 - if this is real then you cannot use `Long` or `long`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    byte[] buffer = new byte[6];
    buffer[0] = (byte)(v >>> 40);
    buffer[1] = (byte)(v >>> 32);
    buffer[2] = (byte)(v >>> 24);
    buffer[3] = (byte)(v >>> 16);
    buffer[4] = (byte)(v >>>  8);
    buffer[5] = (byte)(v >>>  0);
```

That's how `DataOutputStream.writeLong()` does (except it writes all the bytes, or course)

Comment: and first line have to be number 40? not 64?

Comment: No, 40. You want to throw away the first 40 bits (5 bytes) of the long, and keep the 6th byte (starting from the right)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `ByteBuffer`

```
Long number = 0x001122334455667788L;
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
buffer.putLong(number);
byte[] full = buffer.array();       
byte[] shorter = Arrays.copyOfRange(full, 2, 8); // get only the lower 6
```

Answer (score 1):

`java.lang.BigInteger` `toByteArray()`

Comment: I need just last 6 bytes

Comment: Use the last 6 elements of returned array.

Answer (score 1):

How about using DataOutputStream?

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); // This will be handy.
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(baos);
try {
  os.writeLong(number); // Write our number.
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  try {
    os.close(); // close it.
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
return Arrays.copyOfRange(baos.toByteArray(), 2, 8); // Copy out the last 6 elements.
```

Answer (score 1):

A `BigInteger` will do it too.

```
BigInteger number = new BigInteger("001122334455667788", 16);
byte[] b = number.toByteArray();
// May need to tweak the `b.length - 6` if the number is less than 6 bytes long.
byte[] shortened = Arrays.copyOfRange(b, b.length - 6, b.length);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(shortened));
```